# How I can remove the unnecessary top padding of the Navigation view?

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, android-design-library, android-navigationview

There's an unnecessary top padding between the header and the first item shown in this picture.

[image]

How it can be removed?

you can find the source code here:
https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: Just in case you think that is an error, it is not, rather it is part of the Material Design Guidelines. http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/lists.html#lists-specs  It should be there is you are trying to keep it up to google standard. It is 8dp padding.

Comment: I don't mean the header, I know it's a guideline.
what I meant is the top padding between the first item and the header.

Comment: Yes I know that.  That is supposed to be there. it is part of the guidelines. Have a look at the image here.  There is an 8dp seperator. And it is in all of the Latest google Material Apps.  http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0Bx4BSt6jniD7eUpZcXJRODJvMXc/components_lists_keylines_single5.png

Comment: Gmail update with material design.  But it is only guidelines and could probably be altered.  It is a fairly new support library and I am sure more cusumization will be in the near future. http://images.anandtech.com/doci/8671/Screenshot_2014-10-31-22-58-47.png

Comment: Well, you are right but it should give me some control as I think it gives an ugly look when the item is selected.

Comment: I thought the same exact thing when I implemented material design a while back.  It grows on you, I am sure if it is not customizable now, it will be in the near future.

Comment: I didn't like the top padding at first either. But @EugeneH is right, it's the "official" material design spec, and it's definitely intentional. The more I use it, the more it seems to make good design sense. Depending on what is displayed in the header view, there can be some visual confusion without padding to distinguish list items from header.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`NavigationView` seeks to match the material design [specs for the navigation drawer](http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) which state an 8dp space between content areas. Generally there are no ways to override `NavigationView` to specifically break the specifications.

[image: material design specs]

Comment: You can override this value easily. May be this padding can be added programmatically to avoid this case.

Answer (score 58):

You can override predefined dimensions at your `dimens.xml` as;

```
<dimen name="design_navigation_padding_top_default" tools:override="true">0dp</dimen>
<dimen name="design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding" tools:override="true">0dp</dimen>
<dimen name="design_navigation_padding_bottom" tools:override="true">0dp</dimen>
```

Other possible values are here: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/res/values/dimens.xml

Comment: @kishorejethava could you please check the resource files under the generated folder? it may be the classic "clean - rebuild" case

Comment: People these values are found at https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/res/values/dimens.xml

Answer (score 31):

You should read the Ian's answer.
The NavigationView follows the Material guidelines and you should not break these specs.

However, **currently**, you can override this value in your project.

Just add to your `dimens.xml`:

```
<dimen name="design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding">0dp</dimen>
```

**Warning:**

- in the future the Android Team can change this value!
- the same value is applied to each separator in the list

The `NavigationView` uses a `LinearLayout` as header view.
You can see this layout in the source code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:paddingBottom="@dimen/design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding" />
```

Comment: @headsvk Thanks. Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

very simple step :
add the following attribute to your base application theme (stylename=AppTheme) Style.xml :

```
        <item name="listPreferredItemHeightSmall">18dp</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is answered here [Gabriele's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30584554/how-i-can-remove-the-unnecessary-top-padding-of-the-navigation-view)

Just add to your *dimens.xml*:

`<dimen name="design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding">0dp</dimen>`