# NavigationView: how to insert divider without subgroup?

Tags: android, android-support-library, divider, navigationview, android-navigationview

How I can put a divider without title Subgroup in the new NavigationView?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_armario"
        android:icon="@drawable/armario"
        android:title="@string/armario"  />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_amigos"
        android:icon="@drawable/amigos"
        android:title="@string/amigos" />

</group>

<item android:title="Configuración">
    <menu>
        <item

            android:id="@+id/drawer_ajustes"
            android:icon="@drawable/ajustes"
            android:title="@string/ajustes" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_ayuda"
            android:icon="@drawable/ayuda"
            android:title="@string/ayuda" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_sign_out"
            android:icon="@drawable/sign_out"
            android:title="@string/sign_out" />

    </menu>

</item>
```

I would like to put a line beetween amigos and ajustes items without Configuración title.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Use Jin's answer. It works.

Answer (score 58):

All you need to do is define a `group` with an unique ID. I looked through `NavigationView`'s implementation, and it will create a divider every time the group id is changed.

e.g.

```
<group android:id="@+id/my_id">
    <!-- Divider will appear above this item -->
    <item ... />
</group>
```

Comment: Ooooh, I need to try this! I hope it works because this has been bugging me. I'll test it out and report back!!

Comment: Set `<dimen name="navigation_separator_vertical_padding">0dp</dimen>` to remove the padding when you do this unless you want each group to have padding.

Comment: @DanBrough how do you use the vertical specify in menu item ? by defining <dimen name="navigation_separator_vertical_padding">0dp</dimen>

Comment: @DanBrough how does that help removing padding of divider. :\ can you review your coment?

Comment: Its now called "design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding". Read about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30584554/how-i-can-remove-the-unnecessary-top-padding-of-the-navigation-view

Answer (score 6):

I tried this and it worked

<strike>[See implementation from line no 122-125](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/src/android/support/design/internal/NavigationMenuPresenter.java#L122)</strike>

This is my menu file and it is creating the separator:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MyFirstMNCActivity">
    <group android:id="@+id/grp1">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_item_1"
            android:checked="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:title="@string/navigation_item_1" />

    </group>

    <group android:id="@+id/grp2">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_item_2"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:title="@string/navigation_item_2" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
NavigationMenuView navMenuView = (NavigationMenuView) navigationView.getChildAt(0);
navMenuView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(appContext,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));
```

Here is the gist of DividerItemDecoration

[DividerItemDecoration.java](https://gist.github.com/alexfu/0f464fc3742f134ccd1e)

Comment: Can I change the height of addItemDecoration line to 1px?

Comment: yes, you can update it in DividerItemDecoration.i guess it is already 1px. if not update it to 1px;

Comment: How? Is there any method to do so? `addItemDecoration` doesn't accept any parameter which decides the size of the line

Answer (score 3):

**Using xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
...
app:itemIconTint="@android:color/black" 
... />
```

**Programmatically**

```
 yourNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

I feel that is good answer.

Best Luck.