# Android NavigationView menu group divider

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-design-library

Android support design library provide NavigationView:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    ...
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_items" />
```

menu/navigation_drawer_items:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item .../>
        ...
    </group>

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item .../>
        ...
    </group>

</menu>
```

How to add divider, separator or space between groups (like on picture)?

[image]

Comment: add <item><menu> [your items] </menu></item>...

Answer (score 216, accepted):

Just **give a unique id to each group.** It will create a separator automatically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:id="@+id/group_feature"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/navdrawer_item_map"
            android:checked="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer_map"
            android:title="@string/navdrawer_item_map"/>

    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/group_settings"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/navdrawer_item_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer_settings"
            android:title="@string/navdrawer_item_settings"/>

    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: can you tell me how add color to this line

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if you have groups in different layout files.

Comment: @YaseenAhmad http://stackoverflow.com/a/30731387/3544839 to chnge the color

Comment: Creating a group did not work for me. I did figure out that this style

    <item name="android:itemBackground">@drawable/menu_divider</item>

Lets you set the background for the menu item so you can create a divider for each menu item. However, I would like a divider just between groups.

Comment: @RichMorey Creating a group doesn't work.
**You have to give them an unique ID.**

Comment: now it is not working with latest sdk?

Comment: yeah it's working

Comment: Calling MenuCompat#setGroupDividerEnabled(Menu, boolean) may still be necessary here.

Comment: @sgibly this is working for ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.* Styles. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

you do something like this.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
            android:title="Home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_messages"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_event"
            android:title="Messages" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_friends"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_headset"
            android:title="Friends" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_discussion"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_forum"
            android:title="Discussion" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Sub items">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
                android:title="Sub item 1" />
            <item
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_forum"
                android:title="Sub item 2" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

this code is taken from the Design Library example app made by Chris Barnes https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: Your solution works and its add subtitle, which is nice, but question was just about separator. If I omit title, there is divider but also space where should be title.

Comment: you dont need a title, all you have to do is give the item an id

Comment: @Shaddow see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790420/how-to-get-dividers-in-navigationview-menu-without-titles#30790420

Comment: items from second section don't get selected with this solution

Answer (score 11):

I'm using it this way:

```
<group
        android:id="@+id/group1"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu1"
            android:icon="@drawable/somedrawable"
            android:title="Lorem ipsum" />
</group>
<group
        android:id="@+id/group2"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu2"
            android:icon="@drawable/somedrawable"
            android:title="Dolor it amet" />
</group>
```

IDs are important (+id/group1 and +id/group2). Without ids you won't see divider. It is working in my app.

Answer (score 2):

Divider in NavigationMenuList achieved using grouping the Menu items but make sure you are giving group id  @+id that is necessary.
**Below is working code for you**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group
    android:id="@+id/gp_one"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_avatar"
        android:title="Home" />
</group>

<group
    android:id="@+id/gp_two"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_account"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_avatar"
        android:title="My Account" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_orders"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_avatar"
        android:title="My Orders" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_wishlist"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_avatar"
        android:title="My Wishlist" />
</group>

<group
    android:id="@+id/gp_three"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_rateus"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_avatar"
        android:title="Rate Us" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_avatar"
        android:title="Share" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_avatar"
        android:title="Logout" />
</group>
```

Comment: For divider we'll have to divide them in separate groups ? Actually I'm using `BottomNavigationView`

Answer (score 1):

You can add your text between `<item android:title="title_name">` and `</item>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_display_image"
            android:title="Load Image"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            app:showAsAction="always"

            app:actionLayout="@layout/switch_nav_drawer"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="Saved News" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Gallery" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="Slideshow" />

    </group>

    <item android:title="Settings">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
                android:title="Tools" />
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/about_us"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_black_24dp"
        android:title="About Us"></item>


</menu>
```