# Setting a divider between items in options menu

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I'm trying to add a divider to my toolbar option menu, and i can't make it to work.
How can I add a divider as shown in the image below:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30916946/android-navigationview-menu-group-divider

Comment: Which Android version you use?

Comment: hi @ssh, I'm using android 6.0

Answer (score 3):

For Android 6.0 Google [remove dividers.](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html)

Material Themes doesn't display it.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this code :

```
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <group android:id="@+id/grpSort" android:checkableBehavior="single" >
     <item
        android:id="@+id/action_sort"
        android:checked="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_sort"
        android:title="@string/sort" />
   </group>

   <group android:id="@+id/grpHelp" android:checkableBehavior="single" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_Help"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
        android:title="@string/help" />
   </group>
```

It's important to add a unique id to each `<group>`.

Comment: Thanks, I saw this option in other questions and it didn't work for me.
I wonder, maybe the problem is that the divider has the same color as the background, so it actually, transparent?