# Menu group in toolbar need item dividers

Tags: android, xml, toolbar

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_filter"
        android:icon="@drawable/arrows_sync_icn"
        android:orderInCategory="102"
        android:title="Filter"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        >

        <menu>

            <group android:id="@+id/group_1">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/action_latest_story"
                    android:title="Latest stories"
                    />
            </group>
            <group android:id="@+id/group_2">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/action_most_liked"
                    android:title="Most liked"
                    />
            </group>
            <group android:id="@+id/group_3">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/action_most_shared"
                    android:title="Most shared"
                    />
            </group>
            <group android:id="@+id/group_4">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/action_most_read"
                    android:title="Most read"
                   />
            </group>

        </menu>

    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_notification"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/lyt_notification_count"
        android:icon="@drawable/notification_navigation"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        android:title="Notification"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search_navigation"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

So this is what  I'm doing now. I need to draw a item divider between each item(Orderincatogory = 102). I don't know how to do that please help if anyone know the answer. These are in toolbar and I'm testing in kitkat and lollypop device.

Comment: put each item in separate group.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30917121/1527458

Comment: Thank you both but I already tried it and its not a navigation drawer.