# Add borderline between items in menu xml of navigation drawer

Tags: android, xml, material-design

**Gmail app:**
[image: Gmail app]

**My app:**
[image: My app]

**menu/drawer.xml:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        [..]
        <item
            android:id="@+id/settings_sub"
            android:title="Settings">
            <menu>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/settings"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
                    android:title="@string/settings" />
            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

I tried to add a borderline with this xml, but I can't set `android:title` invisible to make `@+id/settings` to the only visible item in `@+id/settings`.

**How to get a simple borderline between two items like its shown in the gmail drawer above?**

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790420/how-to-get-dividers-in-navigationview-menu-without-titles#30790420

Comment: @tyczj That was awsome! Thank you so so much! Search for hours ;)

Answer (score 0):

**To clear up:**

Add this additional instead of only one `<group />`.

```
<group android:id="@+id/my_id">
    <!-- Divider will appear above this item -->
    <item ... />
</group>
```

**Result:**
[image]

**Source:**

[How to get dividers in NavigationView menu without titles?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30790746/4406921)